# Adding same layout more than once in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building a form that contains details like name, phone number and so on. I want to give a button to add similar form to add more similar details. I want to give different id's to the element of layout that gets added on button click.

Ex : if EditText name has an id name for first form, then for the second form I want to have the id secondName.

I am unable to achieve this smoothly.

Please suggest a way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: you can use same layout to multiple activities.

Comment: but I want to do it in the same activity only.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way.
You can keep references to each form as `View` objects.

`View formOne = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.section_form, parent, false);`

Then you can get each field as
 `formOne.findViewById(R.id.edit_text1);`
No need to change the IDs

Comment: Ya, but this goes good when you need to have the layout inflated only once. What if I want to inflate the same layout 10 times ?

Answer (score 0):

add to this your layout file

```
<include layout="@layout/YOURSAMELAYOUT" />
```